# Check if a web browser has a certain cookie from external Java program

Tags: java, cookies

Is there a way to check if your browser has a certain cookie from an external Java (not javascript) program. For instance, have Java search the browsers cookies for a certain one, and if it exists return true. There is a very big chance that this is not possible, however I am wondering if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome(Chromium/Safari/Opera/etc on Webkit/Blink) and Firefox store cookies in sql database in user homedir. You can open this database from your program and check/get all you need.